# How to disable highlight of static fields in Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, backlight

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOi2Z.png)It annoys me. How to disable it?

I tried to turn off the backlight via settings-color scheme, but i could not. there is simply no such section that is responsible for such highlighting. Maybe it's the tips? Or can't it be turned off?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: All details within photo.